# jchart2D Multiple Y-axis titles grouped together

Tags: java, graph, charts, jchart2d

I've been using the jchart2D class by Achim Westerman for some time now and just happened upon an instance where I'm trying to make 3 Y-axes on the right hand side of my graph.

The code for making the 3 axes is as follows

```
//Create Y Axis 1
AAxis<IAxisScalePolicy> yAxisShaftSpeed = 
                    new AxisLinear<IAxisScalePolicy>();
yAxisShaftSpeed.setAxisScalePolicy(new AxisScalePolicyManualTicks());
yAxisShaftSpeed.setMinorTickSpacing(10);
yAxisShaftSpeed.setStartMajorTick(true);
yAxisShaftSpeed.setPaintGrid(false);
yAxisShaftSpeed.setAxisTitle(new IAxis.AxisTitle("Shaft Speed (RPM)"));
IRangePolicy rangePolicyYShaftSpeed = 
                    new RangePolicyFixedViewport(new Range(0,225));
//Create Y axis 2
AAxis<IAxisScalePolicy> yAxisWindSpeed = 
                    new AxisLinear<IAxisScalePolicy>();
yAxisWindSpeed.setAxisScalePolicy(new AxisScalePolicyManualTicks());
yAxisWindSpeed.setMinorTickSpacing(10);
yAxisWindSpeed.setStartMajorTick(true);
yAxisWindSpeed.setPaintGrid(false);
yAxisWindSpeed.setAxisTitle(new IAxis.AxisTitle("Wind Speed (m/s))"));
IRangePolicy rangePolicyYWindSpeed = 
                    new RangePolicyFixedViewport(new Range(0,25));
//Create Y axis 3
AAxis<IAxisScalePolicy> yAxisPressure = 
                    new AxisLinear<IAxisScalePolicy>();
yAxisPressure.setAxisScalePolicy(new AxisScalePolicyManualTicks());
yAxisPressure.setMinorTickSpacing(10);
yAxisPressure.setStartMajorTick(true);
yAxisPressure.setPaintGrid(false);
yAxisPressure.setAxisTitle(new IAxis.AxisTitle("Pressure (hPa)"));
IRangePolicy rangePolicyYPressure = 
                    new RangePolicyFixedViewport(new Range(700,1100));
```

I then go on to add and set the right hand Y axes as follows

```
timePlotZoomableChart.setAxisYRight(yAxisShaftSpeed,0);
timePlotZoomableChart.addAxisYRight(yAxisWindSpeed);
timePlotZoomableChart.addAxisYRight(yAxisPressure);
```

Unfortunately, when the graph comes up, the three Y axes are on the right as expected but all the titles are stacked up on each other under the first added right Y axis (yAxisShaftSpeed). Anyone have any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

might be a bug (I never tested this). Feel free to post a bug report including the minimal runnable code, the version of jchart2d, the OS and java version at sourceforge. 
kind regards, 
Achim